# What sort of statements are legal in a Java 'for loop' incrementer?

Tags: java, variables, loops, for-loop, declaration

In studying for the OCP Java Programmer Exam, I was slightly surprised to see this is legal syntax:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++, System.out.print("howdy ")) ;
```

This got me thinking! On testing some similar things I found this doesn't compile:

```
for(;; int j = 0) ;
```

Couldn't find much info on this. Could anyone provide a reference or explain why declaring a new variable in the incrementer part doesn't compile but other statements (method calls etc.) do? And is it just (for loop scoped) variable declarations or are any other types of statements not allowed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of statements are valid (see the link provided by alexei), but you have to take a look at the scope of the expressions to understand why this initializing wouldn't work:

The scope is over all iterations of the for loop (rather than a new scope each time). The first part gets executed only once, but the second and third get executed at the end of each loop. Hence if you put a declaration in the third part, it gets declared several times (which isn't allowed).

Answer (score 1):

Syntax of for loop is defined in JLS:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I didn't fully realise a LocalVariableDeclaration isn't a StatementExpression (...but I do now!)

Answer (score 1):

The complete explanation can be found in the [Java Language Specs, chapter 14.14.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#14.14.1)

Excerpt:

```
BasicForStatement:
    for ( ForInit_opt ; Expression_opt ; ForUpdate_opt ) Statement

ForInit:
    StatementExpressionList
    LocalVariableDeclaration

ForUpdate:
    StatementExpressionList

StatementExpressionList:
    StatementExpression
    StatementExpressionList , StatementExpression
```

All three "parts" are optional and ForInit and ForUpdate are expression lists, where each statement is spearated with a comma.